# disco upgrade sound mutes after login, vlc doesn't close properly

Tags: sound, vlc, 19.04, media, background-process

I've discovered, that after my Upgrade to Disco, a few seconds after Login I can see that my sound get's muted from something.

Additionally if I play a video with vlc, and close the window during playback is running, vlc won't close and I can't open a new instance until I kill the old instance. If I fist press the stop button before closing the window, vlc terminates properly.

I tried it with Cinnamon and the default Ubuntu desktop and it's on both the same.

So, for me it's clear it's nothing Desktop or vlc related, there's something else doing stuff, but how I can I found out what in order to fix this?

Regards,
L

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can see a few debugging options here. At first, can you run vlc from the command line (from a terminal in graphical mode)? It will allow you to see the output and you might find what the problem is directly from there.

At second, can you run alsamixer and check if something is not right there? E.g., if the sound is getting muted, you should be able to see it in alsamixer.

Based on your findings, we can try planning further troubleshooting steps.

Comment: I checked both, can't see any helpful output, that would indicate a vlc problem. I also created a new user, to ceck if it's to my users config related, but sadly it's not, the new users has the same behaviour.

Comment: If you boot up with Live-USB or Live-DVD, do you have the same problem?